# What resources are people using for TDD in ASP.NET MVC using Rhino Mocks?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mocking, rhino-mocks

Does any know or use and good resources for TTD with ASP.NET MVC specifically with Rhino Mocks.

1. Do you prefer any other Mocking Framework?

My choice on Rhino Mocks is simply because it seems the one which is most up to date and from what I have read is extremely capable!

Comment: I prefer Moq, cause i'm relatively new to mocking concepts and it seems easier one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't looked into it already, I'd recommend using [MvcContrib's TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/).  I tried to mock out my controllers and views and yadda yadda yadda but found myself getting in way over my head, and TestHelper does what I need it to (set controllers up so that I can test them).
Internally it uses Rhino Mocks in places, but you could just as easily use Moq on your end if that makes your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/Rhino%20Mocks

Taught me a good deal about Rhino Mocks.

(Is this what you are asking?)